# order by mysql values like .58

Tags: mysql

`carat` field contains values like `.58`(0.58). I need to get all records order by carat .  I tried to play with cast but no luck, is that posible at all?
Thanks

Comment: I think that you are going to have to supply some additional information...  This is just not enough.

Comment: If carat is a numeric value it should sort just fine. If it's a text valued column you will get it sorted as text, but it will definetly sort. Have you tired it at all?

Comment: Can you put your table structure here? With existing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `carat` is text field then this should work:

`ORDER BY carat*(1.0);`

```
ORDER BY CAST(carat AS DECIMAL(33,22));
```